# Implementing custom loss with paramters to be updated

Tags: tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I'm trying to implement the loss function, using tensorflow, that is used in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.03909.pdf), but I'm having difficulties doing that. Here is what I tried:

```
a = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.5, trainable=True)
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=0.5, trainable=True)
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, a, b, lambda_val=0.1):
    cross_entropy = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True)(y_true, y_pred)
    term1 = (a * tf.exp(b) - 1) ** 2
    term2 = lambda_val * (a ** 2)
    loss = cross_entropy * (1 + term1) + term2
    return loss


model.compile(
        optimizer="adam",
        loss=custom_loss
    )
```

But this does not work

Can you help please. Thank you